# ggplot2 does not display legends for features within geom_abline

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble getting ggplot to display legends for colors and line types when they are only defined within an geom_abline.

I've added a very simple example below.
  It generates the plot as shown (no legends).

I've also tried adding a scale_color_manual to the plot, but that did not appear to do the trick.
  Does anybody know how to make ggplot2 display the legends?

```
library(ggplot2);

xy_data    = data.frame(x=runif(100, min=-0.5, max=0.5), 
                        y=runif(100, min=-0.5, max=0.5));

slope_data = data.frame(slope  = c(-1, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0),
                        model  = paste0("m", seq(1,4)),
                        robust = rep(c("Robust", "Non-robust"), 2))

merged_data = merge(xy_data, slope_data)

slope_plot = 
  ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=xy_data,     aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_abline(data=slope_data, aes(intercept=0, slope=slope, color=model, linetype=robust))

ggsave(plot=slope_plot, file="no_legend_slope_plot.png")
```

[image: Plot: notice missing legends for color and linestyle]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
slope_plot = ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=xy_data, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_abline(data=slope_data, aes(intercept=0, slope=slope, color=model, linetype=robust), show_guide=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: It works. Does anybody know why show_guide=T is NOT the default for geom_abline? It seems counterintuitive to me...

Comment: I suspect that all lines beside `geom_line` are with `show_guide = FALSE` by default, but you need someone wiser than me to know the reason behind that